# Issues with projection when using RGRASS7

Tags: coordinate-system, r, grass-gis, rgrass7

I have just started using `rgrass7` and getting error messages when I try to use `readRAST`. Please see below

```
initGRASS(gisBase="C:/Program Files/GRASS GIS 7.8", mapset = "PERMANENT", override = T)

rast_sgdf <- as(rast, "SpatialGridDataFrame")
writeRAST(rast_sgdf, vname="rast_grass", flags = "overwrite")
```

trying to read rast_grass

```
readRAST("rast_grass")
Error in sp::CRS(getLocationProj()) : 
  PROJ4 argument-value pairs must begin with +: XY location (unprojected)
```

I read somewhere that setting the projection using proj4 will solve this issue, so tried the following

```
execGRASS("g.proj", flags = "c", proj4 = "+proj=utm +zone=45 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
```

but now I get the following error message

```
readRAST("rast_grass")
Error in sp::CRS(getLocationProj()) : 
  PROJ4 argument-value pairs must begin with +: PROJCS["unknown",
    GEOGCS["wgs84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",87],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]
```

Can somebody please help?

data

```
dput(rast)
new("RasterLayer", file = new(".RasterFile", name = "", datanotation = "FLT4S", 
    byteorder = "little", nodatavalue = -3.4e+38, NAchanged = FALSE, 
    nbands = 1L, bandorder = "BIL", offset = 0L, toptobottom = TRUE, 
    blockrows = 16L, blockcols = 128L, driver = "", open = FALSE), 
    data = new(".SingleLayerData", values = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 1208.45349121094, 1207.15441894531, 1207.19006347656, 
    1207.94274902344, 1207.89782714844, 1207.94274902344, 1209.11303710938, 
    1210.1640625, 1208.50305175781, 1209.26330566406, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1208.56213378906, 
    1207.99792480469, 1207.19848632812, 1207.94274902344, 1207.94274902344, 
    1208.01794433594, 1208.43347167969, 1208.52490234375, 1210.61877441406, 
    1209.56994628906, 1212.35241699219, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1208.55212402344, 1208.19763183594, 
    1207.61181640625, 1207.9072265625, 1208.43347167969, 1208.53259277344, 
    1208.56506347656, 1208.56506347656, 1209.91125488281, 1209.72192382812, 
    1217.07543945312, 1219.02136230469, 1219.72485351562, 1217.35620117188, 
    1214.68359375, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    1208.24816894531, 1208.21142578125, 1207.71325683594, 1207.91076660156, 
    1208.19030761719, 1208.56506347656, 1208.53442382812, 1208.56506347656, 
    1211.30285644531, 1215.82885742188, 1214.61682128906, 1221.67639160156, 
    1220.3544921875, 1219.9892578125, 1217.69470214844, 1221.14685058594, 
    1219.81823730469, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    1208.55249023438, 1208.02697753906, 1208.017578125, 1207.400390625, 
    1208.65942382812, 1208.56506347656, 1208.53625488281, 1208.76940917969, 
    1208.76940917969, 1208.76940917969, 1208.76940917969, 1209.5849609375, 
    1217.29479980469, 1222.43395996094, 1220.53955078125, 1222.69262695312, 
    1221.01965332031, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    1208.05090332031, 1207.9970703125, 1207.96997070312, 1208.05041503906, 
    1208.76940917969, 1208.76940917969, 1208.76940917969, 1208.76940917969, 
    1208.76940917969, 1209.5849609375, 1209.5849609375, 1209.5849609375, 
    1222.4541015625, 1220.85107421875, 1221.82141113281, 1216.05773925781, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1208.44177246094, 
    1208.52172851562, 1208.26806640625, 1208.46484375, 1208.78295898438, 
    1207.81494140625, 1208.16723632812, 1208.69140625, 1209.5849609375, 
    1209.5849609375, 1209.5849609375, 1209.720703125, 1213.89770507812, 
    1214.76220703125, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1209.41796875, 1208.56091308594, 1208.10803222656, 
    1208.53002929688, 1208.42626953125, 1207.88256835938, 1208.81066894531, 
    1208.83459472656, 1209.5849609375, 1209.52807617188, 1209.81579589844, 
    1214.59741210938, 1223.80065917969, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1208.49841308594, 
    1209.14697265625, 1208.54370117188, 1208.89050292969, 1209.81579589844, 
    1209.81579589844, 1214.78759765625, 1221.84899902344, 1223.90710449219, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1208.6904296875, 1208.94995117188, 1209.23315429688, 
    1209.67565917969, 1209.67565917969, 1214.1171875, 1215.07580566406, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 1208.83178710938, 1208.76831054688, 1209.67565917969, 
    1209.67565917969, 1211.46594238281, 1214.94274902344, 1215.39904785156, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1209.25732421875, 1208.86218261719, 1209.048828125, 
    1209.67565917969, 1209.67565917969, 1211.82763671875, 1215.14599609375, 
    1215.67370605469, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1209.06079101562, 1209.17163085938, 
    1208.79455566406, 1209.67565917969, 1209.67565917969, 1213.59326171875, 
    1220.58471679688, 1217.48803710938, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1210.30834960938, 
    1209.05725097656, 1210.30346679688, 1209.67565917969, 1209.67565917969, 
    1215.83471679688, 1222.40283203125, 1218.2578125, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 1209.61926269531, 1210.16052246094, 1210.56823730469, 
    1210.79309082031, 1210.46276855469, 1214.73291015625, 1216.96398925781, 
    1219.07653808594, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1209.46716308594, 1209.22875976562, 
    1210.47521972656, 1210.0283203125, 1210.0283203125, 1212.83312988281, 
    1216.43481445312, 1219.17358398438, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1210.00036621094, 
    1209.9521484375, 1209.96520996094, 1210.0283203125, 1210.0283203125, 
    1213.79821777344, 1217.90661621094, 1219.22473144531, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 1209.54418945312, 1210.26818847656, 1210.0283203125, 
    1210.03039550781, 1210.0283203125, 1212.66833496094, 1216.18420410156, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1209.45166015625, 1209.70434570312, 1209.33239746094, 
    1210.0283203125, 1210.0283203125, 1211.15905761719, 1212.17797851562, 
    1214.48999023438, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1209.94604492188, 1210.36206054688, 
    1210.103515625, 1210.0283203125, 1210.0283203125, 1211.44226074219, 
    1214.18041992188, NA, NA), offset = 0, gain = 1, inmemory = TRUE, 
        fromdisk = FALSE, isfactor = FALSE, attributes = list(), 
        haveminmax = TRUE, min = 1207.15441894531, max = 1223.90710449219, 
        band = 1L, unit = "", names = "nakkhu_hosp_10m"), legend = new(".RasterLegend", 
        type = character(0), values = logical(0), color = logical(0), 
        names = logical(0), colortable = logical(0)), title = character(0), 
    extent = new("Extent", xmin = 333003.9801, xmax = 333403.9801, 
        ymin = 3060402.4038, ymax = 3060602.4038), rotated = FALSE, 
    rotation = new(".Rotation", geotrans = numeric(0), transfun = function () 
    NULL), ncols = 40L, nrows = 20L, crs = new("CRS", projargs = "+proj=utm +zone=45 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"), 
    history = list(), z = list())
```

Comment: I think it would be worth to open an issue at https://github.com/rsbivand/rgrass7/issues.

Comment: Thank you. I raised this as an issue and it has been solved by the package owner now. github.com/rsbivand/rgrass7/issues/32

Answer (score 2):

I think that you're missing the `"SG="` parameter to `initGRASS`.
GRASS GIS is very particular about coordinate reference systems. Since you are creating a "one-off" Location/Mapset with the `initGRASS` command, you must set its coordinate system, using the SG param.

It might make more sense to prepare the GRASS location and mapset in advance, then give the specific gisDbase, location and mapset parameters to initGRASS. To create a location, the easiest is with an existing georeferenced spatial data file. So, from inside R save your `rast` object to a geotiff:

```
writeRaster(rast, "raster.tif")
```

then on the command line

```
grass -e -c <path>/<to>/raster.tif  <your gisDbase>/<your Location>/<your Mapset>
```

The `-e` flag says exit immediately, and the `-c` flag says to use the `raster.tif` to prepare a new location with the CRS of that geotiff, and the path is where the location/mapset  will be created.

Now in R just use those gisDbase, location and mapset names for initGRASS.

Comment: Thank you. This didn't solve the issue. I raised this as an issue and it has been solved by the package owner now.
https://github.com/rsbivand/rgrass7/issues/32